# Trying to add extension=mongodb.so in php --ini files

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04, php-mongodb

Installing mongodb with pecl for php.

Running this command : echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> `php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`

and its throwing permission denied exception like this :- 
bash: `php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`: Permission denied

already tried chmod but no luck yet

Answer (score 1):

Found answer :- you need to switch to super user

just write in your terminal : sudo su

after that execute above command it will work.